# IE 11 'ng' not defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular

I've inherited an ASP.Net / MVC / Angular project coded by an outside consulting company.  Angular is completely foreign to me, 90% of my coding has been in C# but I've managed to fumble my way through a number of small side tasks in this project.

All was well and good until one of our external users attempted to use the app in IE 11.  There are 130+ errors that show in the console just from bringing up the home page.  I've done quite a bit of searching, found all kinds of things related to polyfills and es5/es6 shims etc., but after attempting those changes, the only progress I've been able to make is clearing some of the errors related to unsupported arrow functions and parameter default values.  As those disappear, I'm left with a slew of

`SCRIPT5009: 'ng' is undefined`

errors in the developer tools console.  In almost all those cases, the error relates to trying to reference ng.core as in the following example

```
(function (app) {
    app.Routes = ng.core.
     Injectable()
       .Class({
           constructor: function () {...
```

I'm frankly struggling to even understand whether this is an AngularJS or Angular2 project as both are referenced (i.e., the current code makes use of bundling and creates an angular bundle referencing angular.js, angular-ui-router.js etc., as well as an angular2 bundle that references the angular2 files in the node_modules directory)  Interestingly enough, if I remove the angularjs bundle and the reference to it in the `@Scripts.Render()` of the shared layout.cshtml file, I get the same number of errors which leads me to believe the app was initially started as an AngularJS one but went Angular2 and wasn't cleaned-up.  That being said, there's no project-specific use of TS, only the standard TS files from the npm install are there.

The "'ng' undefined" error feels to me like there's some DI not happening properly but I can't make heads or tails of this.

The mandate to get this working in IE 11 "ASAP" has me ripping out what little hair I have left.  Any pointers on where to even start looking or whether it's obvious from the description that there are architectural choices that have been made which dictate starting over in some sense, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Well `ng` being undefined means that some fundamental Angular component is not being properly imported. It may be failing due to an error in the import or it could be that the `<script>` imports are out of order.

Comment: Are you sure the TS files aren't being bundled etc by webpack and then loaded? Also, do you see a polyfills.ts, i know you said you added them -- but if there was use of the CLI for the angular 2 portion, there would have been a polyfills.ts, see if there are some polyfills commented out etc. Also what version of angular 2? check out the package.json

Comment: I should clarify re: TS files - the standard ts files are there, the app itself isn't using them for any of the custom code.  As far as the version, 5 minutes ago package.jsn had 2.0.0-rc.1 but I was reading some and wanted to get it off the rc version, did an npm update and now it's at 2.4.10